# Is there a practical way for a software developer in the UK to join the reserves?

Tags: united-kingdom, software-development, work-life-balance

I am a mid-level software developer not currently a reservist.

[This link](https://jobs.natwestgroup.com/posts/the-army-reserves-and-a-full-time-job-finding-a-balance) shows a case study where the reservist serves

> Tuesday evenings and weekends as and when required – usually one to two times a month. And also a two week annual deployment.

and

> All an employer has to do is offer their support fairly, like allowing me to use my holidays for reservist activities. But RBS actually gives members of the military reservists an **additional two weeks paid leave** to undertake their annual deployment exercises

If I am not a reservist yet but want to become one in the future, how does one tactfully raise or find this kind of flexibility to a prospective employer? Are there alternative approaches/strategies for gaining this flexibility or avoiding sacrifice of all non-work holiday?

I should add that whilst the UK does have a 'cyber reserves' their requirements are much higher and more specialised than a run of the mill full-stack developer.

Comment: I edited out the "adapt or die" bit as it added nothing to the question.

Comment: A software developer in the UK would normally have much more than 2 weeks of vacation, so you should not have to use all your vacation for reserve activates.

Answer (score 10):

> how does one [...] find this kind of flexibility to a prospective employer?

The UK Government maintains a [list of business that have signed the Armed Forces Covenant](https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/armed-force-corporate-covenant-signed-pledges), a pledge to support our armed forces. Such employers are obviously far more likely to be flexible around offering additional benefits and flexibility to reservists than the average.

Answer (score 2):

I had a colleague in a previous job who was a reservist. He was prior to joining and was able to negotiate for the extra two weeks to use for reserve training/deployment. This went down well as some of our executives were ex-military.

I assume (once you've joined up) that its something to mention in applications/cv/cover letter as its both an interesting thing, and should be providing you with transferable skills to talk about in interviews or on your applications.

Then during interviews there is usually a chance to bring up things you want to talk about, you might ask whether they have a policy on reservists or whether they would be able to accommodate two weeks extra reservist leave. Or you could state its a dealbreaker. Remember an interview is for you to decide you like the company and the terms of employment just as much as its for them to decide they like you.

Answer (score 1):

As a US reservist, you only muster one weekend a month and two weeks for annual training. That unfortunately usually means classes to maintain soldiering skills proficiency, vehicle (if applicable) and certification maintenance — very rarely does that mean actual military job use. It gets very old after a while. Most US employers don't comp for holidays/weekends (you're essentially working a 2nd job). By US law (USERRA), you are not required to use your PTO/holiday leave to cover the two weeks of annual training or unit activations (6-18 month deployments) and ensured your job afterward, I would assume there's similar laws in the UK.

Discuss it with potential/current employers: some might respect you more because of it but (in the US) veterans make up less than 6% of the total population, steadily declining, and even less of non-retired workers. In reality, it can be seen as a liability to lose an employee for 2 weeks every year and potentially 6-18 months if they are activated while also needing to hire on temporary help until their return.

Speaking from first-hand experience with the US military: you are a soldier first and your military occupation is secondary. That means you might be trained as a cyberwarfare specialist but, if I need a guntruck driver, you're a driver until otherwise told. Worse case, if I need someone to sit on a desk in an empty lobby, please enjoy the chair. In 2013, US private military contractors did a lot of the more specialized tech work with troops in supporting roles.

Finally, US military service pays very, very little compared to the private sector. I would highly recommend doing research into the UK pay scales, especially since you may be looking at 6-18 month blocks where you monthly pay is lowered significantly.

Comment: Companies are not supposed to use the fact your a reservist against you, but you are also given the ability, to satisfy the entire years requirement at once (this was done by someone in my office).  Needless to say since this worker was doing shift work, their supervisor had to fill in their shifts, so likelihood is that it wasn’t completely ignored.  Of course they ultimately failed to satisfy the certificate requirements for the job and were let go. The point is, being a reservist shouldn’t harm your career, but it’s not likely to advance it.

Answer (score 1):

Odds are you'll have to quit your job to become a member of the military.  While employers are flexible hiring reservists, they can't generally find the flexibility for you to perform basic training and specialty training.

Basic takes eight to twelve weeks (depending on branch of service) and first tier specialty training (A school in the USA) can take between eight to twenty weeks.  As a enlisted, odds are you aren't getting more training initially; but, you might eventually need additional classification training, which of course adds weeks (eight to just over a year).  Odds are you will have to perform basic and specialty training, but not (at least not initially classification training).

I know of very few employers, even those supportive of the military, which would authorize 20 weeks off to complete this training; and, most employers have provisions in their handbooks about taking on a second job, which military service would apply.  That said, some employers are sympathetic, and might allow you to take unpaid leave for your initial training.

Hiring on to a new job as a reservist is a different matter.  Most employers were sympathetic to the training schedule.  Many will even pay you wages (though not required to do so) when you take your two weeks of yearly training.  That's important because you'll discover that military pay is a small fraction of what you would earn on your regular job.  Training is often done in groups, scheduled, and can be communicated early enough for your employer, to find people to cover you.

In my six years as a reservist, I ran into one employer that attempted to break the law, by claiming that my "training time" didn't count for my "time with the company."  They let me go "just" before some contractual provisions would kick in, and I considered fighting them on the point; but, they were out of money, so I wasn't going to win anything anyway.

Finally, there's the whole reason the reserves exist: activation.  I was activated into a war, during which I fought for about six months.  Most employers make vague comments about attempting to hold your position (or promises to attempt to rehire after you return); but, they often aren't required to hold it.  In my case, I didn't even know for how long I'd be gone; and, upon returning I didn't attempt to hire back at an old employer.

All in all, it was a bit of a hassle.  It didn't help my civilian employment a single bit.  Even though I became a sergeant (equivalent) in charge of a team of people in the military, in civilian life they never made the connection that I could run a team.  Those promotions went to the people that were always available (never had to leave for training).

Answer (score 0):

> Are there alternative approaches/strategies for gaining this
> flexibility

You might find it easier to negotiate a 4% higher salary and 10 days of unpaid leave per year, rather than asking for 10 extra days of paid leave, even though the results are exactly the same.

This is because it's common for employees to take unpaid leave - for example, new parents returning to the workforce part-time, and people caring for ailing loved ones. There are some statutory rights to flexible working in this regard (once you've been with an employer for some time) so companies have to have a procedure for this.

IMHO the more important question is **what happens if you get called up?**

If you're an individual developer on a team it might not be a problem - but if you're planning to become an important cog in the machine, the prospect of 6-month surprise absences might make people reluctant to give you extra responsibilities.